# Very small black video at the beginning after using ffmpeg to crop video?

Tags: python-3.x, ffmpeg, pyffmpeg

So I have a video that I am trying to crop with ffmpeg and does crop successfully, but the cropped video has about 1 second of black video at the start.
[blackFrame video](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1sWqN.png)

I assume it is my lack of knowledge of how to set the right codec or I am splitting a frame somehow.

This is the block of code on how I am cropping my video.

```
import subprocess
import time


def crop_video(original_vid_name, cropped_vid_name, start_time, end_time):
    start_time_timeformat = time.strftime('%H:%M:%S', time.gmtime(start_time))
    end_time_timeformat = time.strftime('%H:%M:%S', time.gmtime(end_time))
    ffmpeg_timecrop_cmd = "-ss {} -to {}".format(start_time_timeformat, end_time_timeformat)
    ffmpeg_quality_codec_cmd = '-q:v 10 -crf 18 -c:v copy -c:a copy -avoid_negative_ts make_zero'
    ffmpeg_cmd = 'ffmpeg {} -i {} {} {}'.format(
        ffmpeg_timecrop_cmd, original_vid_name, ffmpeg_quality_codec_cmd, cropped_vid_name
    )

    subprocess.call(ffmpeg_cmd, shell=True)
```

Please let me know what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Read [this post](https://superuser.com/questions/377343/cut-part-from-video-file-from-start-position-to-end-position-with-ffmpeg) first. `-c:v copy` copies the encoded video stream without re-encoding so `-q:v 10 -crf 18` doesn't do anything. I can't reproduce the problem. Try updating your version of FFmpeg.

Comment: I think I found the problem, it this flag, -avoid_negative_ts make_zero     
,I have no idea what this actually does. Can someone explain this to me?